# Does this weighted mean have a name?

Tags: order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have calculated a type of mean which considers how the sum of the values is shared between individual values, but do not know if it has a name. I've [previously been told](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_June_24#Weighted_average) it is the weighted median, but do not think it is. It is equivalent to if you were to sum values within classes and fit a normal distribution to the totals in each class, but can be calculated when there are only a few values.

Consider values of $3, 7, 15, 30, 40, 60$

Cumulative values: $3, 10, 25, 55, 95, 155$

The arithmetic mean is $\frac{155}{6} = 25.83$, but most of the total is present in the final $3$ values and I want a value that accounts for this and that would be relatively unchanged if we were to add a value of 1 at the start of the series. If we plot the cumulative weights against the individual weights, the value I calculate is where $50\text{%}$ of the total ($77.5$) intersects with the individual values. There is a graphical representation [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Unknown_weighted_average.png).

I calculate it in the following way:

$$30+\frac{(77.5-55)}{40}*(40-30)$$

giving $35.625$. I'll try to explain it mathematically:

$$v_{low}+\frac{(m - c_{low})}{v_{high}} * (v_{high}-v_{low})$$

$v_{low} = 50\text{%}$ of the total intersects above this value

$m = 50\text{%}$ of the total

$c_{low}$ = the cumulative value for $v_{low}$

$v_{high} = 50\text{%}$ of the total intersects below this value

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Comment: It differs from the weighted median (where the weights are equal to the values themselves) only in that you account for where the median line falls within the data block.  It's as though you used a trapezoidal approximation instead of a rectangular one.  I'd probably write code to compute it.

Comment: @scoopfaze Thanks for the formatting adjustments.

Comment: @BrianTung, I don't understand the difference between those, but I've now come across https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.56-1/topics/weighted.median and if I enter the values as both values and weights I get the same answer as mine, so does seem to be a weighted median, but I am still not sure how to distinguish it from the standard one.